Route 53 subdomain not routing correctly to Elastic Beanstalk environment
I have a domain through Squarespace.
I have a NestJS application hosted with AWS Elastic Beanstalk. This is up and running and accessible through the generated domain name.
I have an AWS Amplify application deployed which is set up so the root domain name will show this application. This setup has been done through Route 53.
What I would like to do is set up a subdomain to point to the NestJS app on the Elastic Beanstalk environment.
I have tried many different methods to get this working such as A record pointing to the EC2 instance ipv4 address, a CNAME pointing to the Elastic Beanstalk generated domain name, and an A record alias pointing to the Elastic Beanstalk environment.
I have an SSL certificate which is valid for the subdomain that I am trying to route to the Elastic Beanstalk.
With all of the methods that I have tried, when I access the subdomain, it hangs for a bit but then the request gets cancelled with not much information on why.

I've been trying to get this working for a few weeks but lose hope after seaching the web but not finding a solution.
The domain is flyout.app and the subdomain is server.flyout.app.
It is currently set up with an A record as an alias to the Elastic Beanstalk environment

If I do a "dig" for server.flyout.app It shows an A record which points to the EC2 instance IP address.
Any help would be great!

Look at the 307 and see what the redirect is.  Beyond that, I see what looks to be a DNS resolution error.  Without knowing the domain and subdomain, we can't provide many details.

The redirect is just from http to https

I have set up an SSL certificate and confirmed that the CNAME record for the certificate is added to the records

Do I need to change something in the Squarespace DNS settings? As I understood it, moving the nameservers to AWS means that the records are now managed through Route 53, is that not correct?
